# Updater function with useReducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-state, use-reducer

In react, with useState, I can pass it an updater function to get the current state within the same function. Currently I update a state multiple times within the same function.

Is that possible with a reducer dispatch with useReducer?

Thanks.

```
const someFunc = () => {
// some other computation
const result = someOtherFunc();
setState((state)=>{
// do something with current state
return {...state, result} 
})

const result2 = someOtherFunc2();
setState((state)=>{
// do something with current state
return {...state, result2} 
})
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540401/how-to-get-current-state-inside-usecallback-when-using-usereducer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current state inside useCallback when using useReducer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540401/how-to-get-current-state-inside-usecallback-when-using-usereducer)

Comment: why are you not combining in one? `setState((state)=>{  return {...state, result1, result2}  })`

Comment: I am displaying the state in my UI and also saving the state to my DB in case the app crashes elsewhere. I will take a look at the link above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.
You can do this by grouping all your states in like an initialState variable:

```
import  { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';

const SampleComponent = () => {
    const reducer = (state, action) => ({...state, ...action})
    const initialState = {
        someName: '',
        someCounter: 0,
        isLoading: false
    }

    const [{
        someName, someCounter, isLoading
    }, dispatch ] = useReducer(reducer, initialState )

    useEffect(() => {
       dispatch({ isLoading: true }

       const res = await fetch('https://someapi')
       const json = await res.json()

       if (json) {
           dispatch({ 
               someName: json.someNameValue, 
               someCounter: someCounter + json.someCounterValue, 
               isLoading: false 
           })
       }
    }, [])

    return (
       <>
           <h1>{someName}</h1>
           <span>{someCounter}</span>
       </>
    )

}
```

There maybe other ways to do this, but the way works best for me is to:

1. Declare a reducer: `const reducer = (state, action) => ({...state, action})`
2. Declare all states group in an object state: `const initialState = { someState: '' }`
3. Use useReducer with the state variables and dispatch encapsulated with it: `const [{ someState }, dispatch ] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)`
4. Use dispatch() method to set new values of states: `dispatch({  someState: newValue })` where newValue is any value you want to assign to someState.

Comment: I actually realized I did something stupid because I was updating a dictionary that was assigned to a key in the state.

```// state.key = {}

const {key} = state;

func() {
// won't have access to updated state.key here and did not work as intended
dispatch(key: {...key, newData1: '123'})

dispatch(key: {...key, newData2: '456'})
}
```

I ended up moving the updating to inside the reducer function.

Comment: Did you  mean it did not work when you do ```dispatch(key: {...key, newData2: '456'})```? I think you need to wrap the dispatch in an object, so that will be like ```dispatch({ state: newValue })```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Whatever that can be done with `useState` can also be done by `useReducer`. It is the context that makes us decide on which to use.

Suppose I just want to update my loading state, then `useState` is enough

`const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);`

But let's suppose I have a input form,
if I decide to useState, then it will be kind of like this

```
const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
```

instead of using all these `useState`, I could directly using `useReducer` for this specific application

```
const initialFormValues = {
  name: '',
  age: 0,
  address: '',
};

const reducer = (state, action) =>{
  switch(action.type) {
    case "NAME": return { ...state, name: action.value};
    case "AGE": return { ...state, age: action.value};
    case "ADDRESS": return { ...state, address: action.value};
  }
}

const [formValues, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialFormValues);
```

Now whenever you want to update your input fields in the form, just use dispatch.

Both can do the task. Depending upon the use-case, we can choose the more appropriate one.